# Missing ) Parameter Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website keeps throwing a JavaScript error on the following code snippet:

```
<script>
Ext.onReady(function(
  $('.tab2').click(function(){
    Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-2');
  });
    $('.tab1').click(function(){
    Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-1');
  });
});
</script>
```

The error: SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Ext.onReady(function(
```

should be

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
```

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax error is on this line:

```
Ext.onReady(function(
```

Change it to:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Ext.onReady(function() { //missing ) { here
    $('.tab2').click(function() {
        Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-2');
    });
    $('.tab1').click(function() {
        Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-1');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
  $('.tab2').click(function() {
    Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-2');
  });
    $('.tab1').click(function(){
    Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-1');
  });
});
```

Missing area : `Ext.onReady(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
```

So,Replace like

```
<script>
   Ext.onReady(function(){           //Add here
     $('.tab2').click(function(){
         Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-2');
     });
     $('.tab1').click(function(){
         Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-1');
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax error :

Ext.onReady(function(

Should be this:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way:

```
<script>
Ext.onReady(function(){
    $('.tab2').click(function(){
        Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-2');
    });
    $('.tab1').click(function(){
        Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront('.tab-1');
    });
}
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function body must not be passed in arguments

use

Ext.onReady(function(){`enter code here`

});